# Is there a way to changing Core Data schema without migration during early development?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

At the early stages of development, where data retention is no issue and experimental changes to the schema are expected to be numerous, is there a way to avoid migration? Namely, just to dump the database and start over each time.

Everything I try leads to the error: "The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store".

Lightweight migration looks do-able, but I'll end up lots of unwanted versions and messy code. I'd also like to experiment with relationships (no wise cracks), but understand I'd need to commit to a heavyweight migration afterwards!

If the solution is to [check for the existence of the original database using NSFileManager and delete/remove it if found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165315/update-core-data-database-in-app-update-without-migrating), could someone please show the swift code with an example name of the original database, and how it can be effectively removed.

I've been trying several suggested solutions, such as dragging a copy of the .xcdatamodeld file onto the desktop, deleting the file in xcode and bringing it back in, but I keep getting the error that the model and store are not the same.

Comment: Why not simply delete the installed app in the Simulator or the iPhone and run the project again.

Comment: 100% agree with Sathya

Comment: Thank you! While this suddenly seems obvious, I do not think I would have guessed such a simple solution. Thank to your guidance, I see tools, such as SimPholders and simulator-folders from Nibleworks that help manage the issue of changing folder location for the app folders. For me, right now, it is enough to simply press home twice on the simulator and delete the app entirely. How do I mark this as answered within the comment?

Comment: You could add a check that deletes the SQLite file if it fails to create the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`. Can you share your persistent store coordinator code?

Comment: @mbogh - if I understand correctly, this is the code I am using to save the managed object context to the persistent store:
func save() {
    var error : NSError?
    if(managedObjectContext!.save(&error) ) {
        println(error?.localizedDescription)
    }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered in one line in first comment, but appreciated in reverse proportion.